# Selenium - move page to front

Tags: selenium

I am performing a web page scrape and update using Selenium and phantomJS webdriver. At one stage, completing one page can bring up either page_A or page_B. The page I want is page_B. If page_A appears, I can locate the elements:

```
<li class="menu_item">
  <a class="menu_item_anchor_selected" href="#page_a">Page_A</a>
</li>
<li class="menu_item">
  <a class="menu_item_anchor" href="#page_b">Page_B</a>
</li>
```

and I can then extract the target from the anchor to page_B. However, once loaded by the driver, every element on page_B remains invisible.

```
public class fill_page_B (WebDriver driver, String target) throws Exception
{
    String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl;
    String page_B_Url = currentUrl + target;
    driver.get (page_B_Url);

    // prove that page_B actually loaded
    String page = driver.getPageSource ();
    System.println (page);

    WebElement we = driver.findElement (By.id ("MyId"));

    // ignore test for we exists; it does

    WebDriver wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 60);      // should be long enough!
    wait.until (ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf (we));    // fails

    . . .
}
```

I have tried using:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

and other tricks to ensure the window hasn't shrunk to make the required control outside the viewable window and other, similar tricks to make sure it hasn't migrated off the screen entirely.

I have also tried:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript ("arguments[0].checked=true;", we);
```

to force the element to be visible. This approach however merely threw an Exception "cannot click on option element. Executing JavaScript click function returned an unexpected error etc."

However, when I ran my application again, this time using an Internet Explorer driver, I noticed that when I got page_B (and proved it by displaying the page contents in the system log), page_A was still visible. I did try resizing page_A (which was previously maximized) before getting page_B, but this made no difference; everything on page_B remained invisible and unclickable.

Any suggestions as to how Selenium could deal with this?

Comment: IMO, `extract the target from the anchor to page_B` won't be the best practice. You should _Automate_ the steps just like a _Manual Tester_ would perform

Comment: Correct - *not* the best practice. However, I was able to find a clickable element to call page_B.